# Is there any function like setup in pig udf

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, udf

I want to add mapDB for a file to use by all mappers in the pig UDF. How can i do one time setup of this mapDB object? Do we have any function which will be called only once when pig udf is instantiated?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In pig one has to extend EVALFUNC for the udf to be called for everyline of the record .

The class where evalfunc has been extended can be instantiated by defining it in the beginning of the pig-script .

define ex_arg my.udfs.Extract('true');

this causes instantiation of the class .